# Codeigniter Active record response differnt from MyPhpAdmin SQL query

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, phpmyadmin

I am getting a different result when I execute query in `codeigniter` active record form `MyPhpAdmin`

The following query run using `MyPhpAdmin`

```
SELECT * FROM (`ingredients`) LEFT JOIN `product_ingredients` ON `ingredients`.`ingredient_id` = `product_ingredients`.`ingredient_id` AND `product_id` = 46
```

gives the desired result which which includes the ingredient_id for both ingredient records that get returned.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ingredient_id] => 1 [display] => Sweet Almond Oil [slug] => sweet-almond-oil [title] => Sweet Almond Oil [description] => Sweet Almond Oil [featured_image_url] => [product_ingredient_id] => 10 [product_id] => 46 [display_position] => 2 [key_ingredient] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [ingredient_id] => 2 [display] => Shea Butter [slug] => shea-butter [title] => Shea Butter [description] => Shea Butter [featured_image_url] => [product_ingredient_id] => [product_id] => [display_position] => [key_ingredient] => ) )
```

But if I execute this query using `Codeigniter` Active record with the following code:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->join('product_ingredients', 'ingredients.ingredient_id = product_ingredients.ingredient_id AND `product_id` = 46', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get('ingredients');
```

Then the resulting array is missing the ingredient_id for the second ingredient result which is:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ingredient_id] => 1 [display] => Sweet Almond Oil [slug] => sweet-almond-oil [title] => Sweet Almond Oil [description] => Sweet Almond Oil [featured_image_url] => [product_ingredient_id] => 10 [product_id] => 46 [display_position] => 2 [key_ingredient] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [ingredient_id] => [display] => Shea Butter [slug] => shea-butter [title] => Shea Butter [description] => Shea Butter [featured_image_url] => [product_ingredient_id] => [product_id] => [display_position] => [key_ingredient] => ) )
```

Any help would be really appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Check it out

```
$this->db->select('i.*');
$this->db->from('ingredients i');
$this->db->join('product_ingredients pi', 'i.ingredient_id = pi.ingredient_id', 'left');
$this->db->where('pi.product_id',46);
$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```